# Google Script loop overwriting all rows

Tags: javascript, loops, google-apps-script

I've written a script to read data from a website using an API and i'd like to write the output in a google sheet. There are 4 data items per ID of a json object and i'd like to write them to 4 columns, C - F, starting in row 2 until row 32.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to put the values of `[current_price,forecast,demand,available_shares]` from the cell "C2" on the active sheet.

For this, how about this answer?

#### Modification points:

- In your script, the value is put to the Spreadsheet with `for (i = 2; i < 33; i++) {}` every each `stockId`. By this, the old value is overwritten by the next value. I think that this is the reason of your issue.
- I think that in your case, the following flow can be used.

  1. An array is prepared before the for loop.
  2. Put the value of `[current_price,forecast,demand,available_shares]` to the array.
  3. When the for loop is finished, the array is put to the Spreadsheet.

By this flow, the value of each `stockId` is put to the array, and then, the array is put to the Spreadsheet. When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function myFunction() {

  let values = [];  // Added

  for (let stockId = 1; stockId < 32; stockId++) {
    if (stockId == 24) continue;
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.torn.com/torn/" + stockId + "?selections=stocks&key=" + API);
    var content = response.getContentText();
    var json = JSON.parse(content);
    var current_price = json["stocks"][stockId]["current_price"];
    var forecast = json["stocks"][stockId]["forecast"];
    var demand = json["stocks"][stockId]["demand"];
    var available_shares = json["stocks"][stockId]["available_shares"];

    values.push([current_price,forecast,demand,available_shares]);  // Added
  }
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();  // Added
  ss.getRange("C2:F" + (values.length + 1)).setValues(values);  // Added
}
```

#### Reference:

- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)